single phase submersible pump auxiliary binding start/run sequential or parallel?
I have a single phase submersible pump which is auxiliary binding that need start and run capacitor.
Does start and run capacitor giving phase shift to be started
a) Sequential (like trigger start capacitor and when it reaches desired speed (75-80%) then turn off start capacitor and turn on run capacitor) ?
b) Parallel (Like trigger start and run capacitor together and turn off start capacitor when it reaches desired speed) ?
Which one is the right approach and why. I searched internet I could find both type of wiring. Both seems to work so it very confusing which one is the right approach. Motor starter with contactor usually triggers them sequentially but without contactor they trigger them parallelly and cut of start capacitor when green start button is released.


https://www.electricalblog.org/single-phase-motor-wiring-diagram-with-capacitor-start-pdf/
yes start and run capacitor create phase difference to provide rotational torque. Run capacitor is always connected to Auxiliary winding. Start capacitor is in series with centrifugal switch. Centrifugal switch opens when a speed is reached,disconnecting the start capacitor. Parallel is right approach. Follow the circuit in the image.
